# Improve performance of UpdateIf in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

Hoping someone can help me improve the performance of an `UpdateIf` statement I am using in PowerApps. Here is the code:

`UpdateIf( Nominations,true, { Status: {Value: "Not Approved"}, 'Approved By': varUser } );`

This works, but takes about 5 minutes to run through 800 records, which feels very slow. I am new to PowerApps, so I don't know what is a reasonable run-time, but again that feels very slow. Can anyone help provide an alternative? I have tried `Update` and `Patch` but to no avail.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What were the processing times with Update or Patch?

Comment: When I set UpdateIf to just true, about 5 minutes for 800 records. I've updated the logic this limit the iterations down to around 2 minutes, depending how I set up the test data. I am new to powerapps so I'm not sure what is typical.

Comment: What is the backend you're updating, or is it a local collection?  e,g, SharePoint/Excel will be slow.  Hopefully you're not using these.

Comment: Ha -it's a SharePoint List.

Comment: Oh no!  Actually SharePoint lists are better than Excel!  In my experience SharePoint performance is very erratic.  I think 5 mins is about right for your 800 updates.

Comment: @Chris2015, Are you trying to update "all records" in the list with same data for Status and Approved By columns?